# Creating a global dynamically-allocted array

Tags: c++

I am new to C/C++ and I had a question about dynamically allocating arrays.  Can you not make a global dynamically allocated array?  What if I wanted arr to be used by multiple functions? Would I have to pass arr to every function? Basically I guess I am still confused on the concept of dynamically allocated arrays and how I could create an array that can be used by a few functions.

The following produces : error: ‘arr’ does not name a type, but I am not sure exactly why.

```
#include <iostream>      

using namespace std;

int * arr = NULL;
arr = new int [10];

int main() {
   arr[0] = 1;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jrok: That's not how C syntax works

Comment: @Eric You're absolutely correct. C doesn't have `new` :)

Comment: @jrok: `int arr* = new int[10]` isn't valid C or C++.

Comment: "Global" and "dynamically allocated" are really mutually exclusive. Global variables have static storage, and dynamically allocated ones have dynamic storage. You *can* of course have a global *pointer to* a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: @NikBougalis http://liveworkspace.org/code/1X8X05$1 I'm not sure I get your point?

Comment: @jrok: you said he should try `int arr* = new int[10];`. Someone pointed out that's not how C syntax works. You replied that C doesn't have `new`. That wasn't the point. The point was that your code wasn't valid C or C++: `int arr*` is not the correct syntax. Look at the `*`.

Comment: Oh :) well that's a typo, nit-pickers. Thanks for pointing it out, anyway :)

Comment: @jrok: nitpicking is *awesome* :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's invalid for the same reason that this is invalid

```
#include <iostream>      

using namespace std;

int a = 0;
a = 2;

int main() {

}
```

You can't run statements outside of a function, only initializers. As a result, this works:

```
#include <iostream>      

using namespace std;

int *arr = new int[10];

int main() {
   arr[0] = 1;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't even have to make the array dynamic, you can just put the array in static memory outside main, and it will live as long as the program.

```
#include <iostream>     

int arr[10];

int main() {
   arr[0] = 1;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have "code" outside of a function. You need to put the call to `new` inside a function - you only have one in your code: `main`, but as long as it is a function that is executed before you access the array, it's fine.

You can also, as the comment says, do `int *arr = new int[10];` - as long as it's part of the initialization, and not on a separate line.

Comment: `int *arr = new int[10]` is perfectly valid in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* arr = new int[10];
```

or (since you are allocate a constant size array):

```
int arr[10];
```